# Automate NiFi Deployment

Tags: apache-nifi

I am looking for best approaches for deploying NiFi flows from my DEV environment to TEST/PROD environments.

Below links gives an overview of how we can achieve the same; basically it explains we have to make use of NiFi Cli to automate the deployment.

https://pierrevillard.com/2018/04/09/automate-workflow-deployment-in-apache-nifi-with-the-nifi-registry/

https://bryanbende.com/development/2018/01/19/apache-nifi-how-do-i-deploy-my-flow

But I was wondering is there an option to **create a general script which can be used for deploying for different types of flows**. Since the variables that we need to set for one processor is different from another one, not sure how we can do the same.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I am the primary maintainer of NiPyAPI, a Python client for working with Apache NiFi. I have an example script covering the steps you are requesting though it is not part of the official Apache project.

https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi/blob/master/nipyapi/demo/fdlc.py

Comment: Chaffelson, the variables and controller services for one processor varies from another. So, how would we control these using a general script ?

Comment: Also would like to know the difference between NiFi Cli and NiPyAPI.. does both provides same functionality or one has more features than another.

Comment: Where possible I would replace them with variables set in the Variable Registry in the top level Process Group, otherwise they can be set using other NiPyAPI/canvas functions provided in the package.  Regarding NiPy Vs CLI, the CLI is a supported part of the official NiFi project with robust but limited features for specific tasks, this compares to NiPy being a general purpose SDK for all NiFi tasks.